# Laravel | Pass a Vue.js value to data-value in blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to pass the value **@{{cash.amount}}** in Vue.js to **data-value**.

```
<td scope="row"  data-value="HERE">@{{cash.amount}}</td>
```

I tried this, but not working.

```
<td scope="row"  data-value="@{{cash.amount}}">@{{cash.amount}}</td>
```

Thank you

Comment: try  `:data-value="cash.amount"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind it like :

```
 <td scope="row"  :data-value="cash.amount">@{{cash.amount}}</td>
```

or

```
<td scope="row"  v-bind:data-value="cash.amount">@{{cash.amount}}</td>
```